# How to match regex expression with url in selenium?

Tags: java, regex, selenium

```
public class Unsplash {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","d:\\selenium\\gecko\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);     
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(1920,0));
        //driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920/2,1080));
        driver.get("http://unsplash.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.className("_32SMR")).click();
        for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
        {
            driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);

        }
        //driver.getPageSource();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/?photo=(.*?)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(driver.getPageSource());
        while(m.find())
        {

            driver.get("https://unsplash.com"+m.group());
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Iam trying to extract href links from unsplash.com to automate it for downloading website the href linksformat is  href="/photos/9l_326FISzk"

for the  code System.out.println(m.group()); Iam just getting "/photos/" as ouput .
How can I get full href url for example "/photos/9l_326FISzk " as output

Comment: What did you try to verify the regEx expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

We can adopt a much easier approach to get the URLs of the images of different Artists using Java Collection. The following code block gets  all the links of the images as per Artist:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Q45106505_REGEX 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);     
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://unsplash.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='_2OLVr _21rCr']/*[name()='svg' and @class='_32SMR']")).click();;
        List<WebElement> elem_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='app']//div[@id='gridSingle']/div[@class='y5w1y' and @data-test='photo-component']//a[contains(@href,'/?photo=')]"));
        List<String> title_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> href_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (WebElement we:elem_list)
        {
            String my_title = we.getAttribute("title");
            title_list.add(my_title);
            String my_href = we.getAttribute("href");
            href_list.add(my_href);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<title_list.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(title_list.get(i)+" at : "+href_list.get(i));
        }


    }

}
```

The Output on the console is as follows:

```
View the photo By timothy muza at : https://unsplash.com/?photo=6VjPmyMj5KM
View the photo By Stephanie McCabe at : https://unsplash.com/?photo=_Ajm-ewEC24
View the photo By John Moore at : https://unsplash.com/?photo=Fdhyrhb9x7o
View the photo By Jason Blackeye at : https://unsplash.com/?photo=KUgDg__TMGk
View the photo By Mahkeo at : https://unsplash.com/?photo=m76_jjV-rRI
View the photo By Samara Doole at : https://unsplash.com/?photo=5VuLCwvZCQU
View the photo By Craig  Whitehead at : https://unsplash.com/?photo=2pdDHpqbKr8
View the photo By Chris Marquardt at : https://unsplash.com/?photo=5KmkrOjOBrE
View the photo By Annie Spratt at : https://unsplash.com/?photo=MN31CWOoEmc
View the photo By Alexandra Kusper at : https://unsplash.com/?photo=T8kr3JLALFU
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: @mythreya Glad to be able to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using matching a regex against the entire `driver.getPageSource()`, the more "Selenium"-ish way to do this is to locate the elements that contain the `href` attribute, then compute your regex.

Assuming you only want to get `href`s from all `<a>` tags on the page:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/?photo=(.*?)");

List<WebElement> aTags = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for (WebElement aTag : aTags) {
    String href = aTag.getAttribute("href");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(href);
    if (m.matches()) {
        // do something with href
    }
}
```